# Post data to Mongodb using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm trying to post a form to my mongodb using angular, but I'm not really sure how to do it. I've already made connection with mongodb with node, and that works, but now I am trying to do it using angular

This is my form:

```html
<form action="/insert" method="post">
      <div class="title-1">Contact</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required/>
          <label>Naam *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" id="adress" name="adress" required/>
          <label>Straat + huisnummer *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" id="postal" name="postal" required/>
          <label>Postcode *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required/>
          <label>Woonplaats *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
         <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required/>
        <label>Email-adres *</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required/>
          <label>Telefoonnummer *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="text" id="quotation" name="quotation" required/>
          <label>Offerte aanvragen voor *</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea> 
          <label>Omschrijving</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Verzenden</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

This is my post in node:

```js
router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
  var item = {
    name: req.body.name,
    adress: req.body.adress,
    postal: req.body.postal,
    city: req.body.city,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    quotation: req.body.quotation,
    message: req.body.message
  };
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db.collection('user-data').insertOne(item, function(err, result){
      assert.equal(null, err);
      console.log('Item inserted');
      db.close();
    });
  });
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: What problem you're facing.

Comment: I am trying to send it asynchronously to my mongo database. Or am I bound by using Ajax for that?